# What does Angular Material SideNav's `fixedInViewport` Property Control

Tags: javascript, angular, layout, angular-material

Within Angular Material Sidenav component, what (if anything) does `fixedInViewport` do?

[The documentation states](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatSidenav):

> Whether the sidenav is fixed in the viewport.

Not helpful.

And when I try out [their StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qrqyvnneorj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html), alternating the value between `true` and `false`, I see ***no*** difference at all in behavior. Height is unchanged, the scroll behavior is the same, position corresponding to the `mode` property is the same.

#### What does this property control?

Comment: It sets various CSS properties such as `position`, `top`, and `bottom`. Try with more "extreme" values for `fixedTopGap` and `fixedBottomGap`. Here is an example in [action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upkx8u). You'll see that the sidebar in opened position is offset on the top and bottom. With your value `56` for `fixedTopGap`, you just can't see the difference as it matches the app/top bar height, but try a number like `250` and you'll see.

Comment: Oh, I see, so without those additional properties it seems to do nothing? Hmm.

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to have much to do with the nav's position in the viewport. Like, at all.

Comment: `fixedInViewport` does set `position` to `fixed`. So on it's own it does something. Depending on the rest of the styles, that position could definitely have an effect.

Comment: And why isn't there a corresponding property on `mat-sidenav-content` or on `mat-sidenav-container`. I usually want the contents to scroll and keep the sidenav in one place.